# ApplicationUser ICollection member not being saved in DB

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've added some properties to ApplicationUser, and two of them are ICollection's.
When I use Update-Database it doesn't generate columns for these two members.

So, what am I missing here? I imagine it's very basic. I'm used to working with Hibernate in Java, where it generates a new table for element collections.

Some code samples -

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public byte[] UserImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<string> Interests { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<string> Friends { get; set; }

}
```

**RegisterViewModel**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Image")]
    public int UserImage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Interests")]
    public virtual ICollection<string> Interests { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Friends")]
    public virtual ICollection<string> Friends { get; set; }

    //........
```

**Task Register(RegisterViewModel model)**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Interests = model.Interests,
                Friends = model.Friends
            };

            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];
            byte[] imgBytes = null;

            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            imgBytes = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

            user.UserImage = imgBytes;


            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            //............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to model your collection items. You could go many to many or one to many.

```
// many to many
public class Interest
{
    public int InterestId { get; set; }
    public string InterestDesc { get; set; } // field can't match class name
}

// one to many
public class Interest
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }  // Make primary key the FK into application user
    public string InterestDesc { get; set; } // field can't match class name
}
```

Then change your collections

```
public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
```

Don't forget to add the DbSet to context. Repeat for Friends and other string collections.